# Finding character no number between two slashes regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex
`(?<=[\/]).*(?=[\/])` I'm trying to run on `FM7-4/E27/U20` and I'm trying to only get the character between the two slashes, no numbers. I tried adding `[^0-9]` but wasn't able to get a match. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\/)[^\/\d]*(?=\d*\/)
```

See the  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ke2uNL/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=\/)` - the `/` char must appear immediately on the left
- `[^\/\d]*` - zero or more chars other than `/` and digits
- `(?=\d*\/)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more digits and then `/` immediately on the right.